# Can't Open Links in New Tab - MuraCMS

Tags: hyperlink, content-management-system, mura

A website I help manage uses MuraCMS. It was brought to my attention that many links are opening in the same tab instead of opening a new one. The target is properly set to _blank so I am not sure what is causing this. Please help! These are normal links to other pages of the site so they shouldn't be encountering anything weird.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the link code? If the target is being set correctly then this is a browser issue. Once the link is generated by Mura and sent to the browser it is all client-side (browser).

Comment: for example: <a href="~~Link~~" target="_blank">Link Name</a></p>
I got rid of the actual link because I don't want to give away where I work.

Comment: If that is your link then something is happening on the browser end to stop the functionality.  Try different browsers. Check your settings.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that you have some JavaScript code that is catching the click event and preventing it from firing. Do you have JavaScript code binding to click events on these pages as well? We will really need to see some code to help with this. What you have told us thus far should work.

Comment: This is why I'm very confused. There's no javascript happening in the background that should bother the links. The only javascript is for the header on the page.